# How to save Application path location into a XML Node

Tags: xml, inno-setup

I have a question, I looked around the internet and I didn't get help.
This is the problem:
- I want to save the Application path location in a XML Node. The problem is that I can't use the consts names for directories because the installer write any word I put there, exactly as how I wrote it.

```
 function NextButtonClick2(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
   begin
    Result := True;
    SaveValueToXML(ExpandConstant('{pf}\XXX\Config.xml'), '//@param', PEdit.Text);
    SaveValueToXML(ExpandConstant('{pf}\XXX\Config.xml'), '//@path', '{app}\XXX\Aplication.exe');
   end;
```

This is the result I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<games> <game priority="0" display="1" param="test" path="{app}\Aplication.exe" id="1036"/> </games>
```

This is the result I expect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<games> <game priority="0" display="1" param="test" path="C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX\Aplication.exe" id="1036"/> </games>
```

The location is properly... but only if I write it manually. And that's a problem, the installer gonna edit the path node from the XML in an automatically way... then if the users have a different hard drive letter [C,D,F,H, etc] or a different path location for the main application, the will get errors during the installation.

Please help!
Thanks from now on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling the ExpandConstant function for the value you want to store, just for the name of the XML.

Change your code to:

```
function NextButtonClick2(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  SaveValueToXML(ExpandConstant('{pf}\XXX\Config.xml'), '//@param', PEdit.Text);
  SaveValueToXML(ExpandConstant('{pf}\XXX\Config.xml'), '//@path',
    ExpandConstant('{app}\XXX\Aplication.exe'));
```

end;

And you'll get what you want.